# unix_timestamp not working as intended

Tags: hive, hiveql

I seem to have trouble with a very simple script in Hive:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp('2018-06-18', 'YYYY-MM-dd')
```

Result: 1514671200

This unix timestamp corresponds to 2017/12/30. What is going on? Why is the behavior not the expected?

Thanks in advance. Can provide more information if needed but this is quite straightforward.

Comment: It should be `SELECT unix_timestamp('20180618', 'yyyyMMdd')` in this format. Just make your YYYY to yyyy.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. Stupid me.